# Can 'Type' be a safe name for a class?

Tags: c#

Is it normal to create a class and give it a name of 'Type'?

What problems could there potentially be?

For example:

```
public class Type 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: It's not normal and that can result in a LOT of problems. `System.Type` is a built-in class that's used in all reflection code. A *lot* of non-generic methods accept a `Type` argument too. And since `using System;` is used in most C# files, you'll have to specify the full namepace + type of your "Type" class every time to avoid compilation errors

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable, but to take your code example literally, if your class is as simple as this it probably should just be something like `Dictionary<int, string>`. C# will allow you to use its reserved keywords....but why tempt fate and risk a ton of needless headache? Also, if you share this code with someone who has worked with reflection and/or Type extensively, you now are going to confuse them. Vague naming helps no one, and is best left to the standard library itself. Be clear and specific in your nomenclature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it normal to create a class and give it a name of 'Type'?

It's unusual, but it's valid.

> What problems could there potentially be?

Basically that if you've got `using System;` and `using YourNamespaceContainingType;` then you'll need to disambiguate to say which `Type` type you mean. That's definitely an annoyance in source code, but it's not going to cause any issues to the runtime.